# Why is UIAlertController not pausing code while it waits for answer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uialertcontroller

My understanding is that normal behavior for a UIAlertController after being presented is to wait for the user to respond in other words pause other code.

In this case when the user clicks save, a UIAlertController is supposed to appear, ask the user a question about saving and then wait for the response. However, the code is continuing and the alert controller gets dismissed after about one second.

What could be wrong with the following that is preventing the code from pausing and causing the alert to disappear after about one second?

```
-(void) save {
if (listView.text.length>=1) {
[self fireAlertNewOrUpdate];
}
// save everything else
//dismiss view controller - this line of code may be dismissing the alert controller...
}

-(void) fireAlertNewOrUpdate {
    UIAlertController *listAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Save list as new?" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
       
       UIAlertAction* yes = [UIAlertAction
                             actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                             handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                             {
                             [self saveNewList];
                                 
                             }];
       UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Update existing" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                {
                                   [self updateExisting];
                                }];
       [listAlert addAction:cancel];
       [listAlert addAction:yes];
       if ([listAlert respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreferredAction:)]) {
           [listAlert setPreferredAction:yes];
       }
       [self presentViewController:listAlert animated:YES completion:nil];
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've given the answer yourself, except that you've also hidden it from us. (Fortunately, you hinted at it in a comment.) It's because there's a line of code you've omitted, in `save`, where you *dismiss the view controller*. That view controller *is* the alert, so the alert appears in response to the call `fireAlertNewOrUpdate` and then immediately disappears again. In effect, you are saying `present / dismiss` in a single breath.

> My understanding is that normal behavior for a UIAlertController after being presented is to wait for the user to respond in other words pause other code

No, not at all true. In fact, just the opposite. Your "other code" just goes right on even after the alert has appeared. There is basically nothing in iOS programming where code will spontaneously "pause". For this reason, it is quite usual after you call `present` to present a view controller to do *nothing* further in that code.

Comment: OK. Thx for the explanation. I guess without realizing it I have always put alerts in their own fork rather than in the midst of code.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "in their own fork". What's a fork? As I said, usually `present` is the very last line of executed code, so the reason there's a pause is merely that your code ended.

Comment: Sorry to keep rattling on, but I hope you understand there is no need to call `dismissViewController` to dismiss the _alert_. It is dismissed automatically when the user taps any of its buttons.

Comment: The dismissViewController is there to dismiss the underlying viewController, not the alertViewController at the end of the save. I mentioned it because I am aware that dismissing any VC will dismiss the alertVC which is at the top of the stack. I was under the incorrect impression that an alertVC halted code but you have thankfully disabused of this misperception.

Comment: Totally cool. So the correct way to do that is include dismissal of the underlying view controller in the completion handler of the action method of all the buttons in the alert. Annoying repetition, I know, but that's life.